# Only list custom user roles (filter array)

Tags: user-roles, arrays, comparison

I use `$available_roles = $wp_roles->get_names()` which results in the following print_r output with all available user roles:

```
Array ( 
  [administrator] => Administrator 
  [editor] => Editor 
  [author] => Author 
  [contributor] => Contributor 
  [subscriber] => Subscriber 
  [customer] => Customer 
  [shop_manager] => Shop Manager 
  [custom_role_test1] => Custom Role Test 1 
  [custom_role_test2] => Custom Role Test 2 
)
```

I have defined a second array with the built in roles from both WordPress and WooCommerce:

```
$built_in_roles = array('administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor', 'subscriber',
'shop_manager', 'customer');
```

Is there a function in PHP available to remove the `$built_in_roles` from the `$available_roles` array?

So that I get an array with the following print_r output:

```
Array ( 
  [custom_role_test1] => Custom Role Test 1 
  [custom_role_test2] => Custom Role Test 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it :)

```
`$arr = array( 'element1' => 1, 'element2' => 2, 'element3' => 3, 'element4' => 4 );

$filterOutKeys = array( 'element1', 'element4' );

$filteredArr = array_diff_key( $arr, array_flip( $filterOutKeys ) );`
```

Result will be something like this:

['element2'] => 2

['element3'] => 3

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#87912